# django template: dynamic variable name in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

In my javascript i want something like this

```
SomeFunction(attribute){
    var prev_rating = {{ u_list.attribute }};
}
```

The function can have three different inputs...  `beauty, wealth, age` . So if I pass `attribute = beauty` to the function, `var prev_rating` should be set to

```
var prev_rating = {{ u_list.beauty }};
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write the value selection in Javascript:

```
var ratings = {beauty: {{u_list.beauty}}, wealth: {{u_list.wealth}}, age: {{u_list.age}} }
function SomeFunction(attribute) {
    var prev_rating = ratings[attribute]
}
```